# Reading json twitter streams with python

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I am pretty new at working with python and coding in general so I feel as though this answer is something that I do not understand about how python works.
I have been working with using Tweepy to collect streams of data from python to measure sentiment with different things.  That part worked fine.  When I ran the program, I had the data write to a txt file and then was trying to use the data within that file to see things such as common words or locations.  But I am running into problems when I am reading the data.  I have been searching online and found a number of different ways that people have read the data but as I am unfamiliar with json files in general, I don't understand why these methods would work or not.
The main error I seem to be running into is something similar to this:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

From my understanding, this means that the data is not reading in correctly as can't be read as a json file.  But I have also experienced the error where it reads like this:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 4 column 1 (char 0).

I don't understand why it would change or not.  I have tried reading the file in as the original txt file and then saving it again as a json file. The first error I received when trying it as a json file with the second coming from the txt file.

I have read a number of different threads discussing similar problems but they keep giving me these types of errors.  Just as an example, here is what my code looked like for the most recent error:

```
import json
source = open("../twitterdata24.json")
json_data = json.load(source)
```

One of my other attempts:

```
import json
tweets = []
for line in open("fileinfo"):
    tweets.append(json.load(line))
```

One other point of interest, the data I am working with contains many individual tweets and from what I have read, I think there is a problem with each individual tweet being a new dictionary, so I tried to make the whole data file a list using [] but that just moved the error down a line.

So if there is anything anyone could tell me or point me to that would help me understand what I am supposed to do to read this data, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks

Edit:
Here is a small sample of the data.  The whole data file is little large so here are the first two tweets in the file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l6uiCzBTYf-SqUpCThQ3WDXmslMcUnPA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `json.load(source)` is, in fact, the correct way to load data from a json file. The problem must be in the files you're reading from. Please share their contents.

Comment: For the second one, you can't do `json.load(line)`. The `load` function takes a _file_. If you want to parse a _string_, you need to use `loads` instead. Also, trying to parse a line is rarely the right thing to do in the first place—JSON documents are allowed to have newlines, and usually do.

Comment: If you have something that sure looks like valid JSON in Notepad but Python gives you an error on line 1 column 1, one common reason is that you've saved it as BOM-encoded UTF-16-LE (the default text encoding for many Windows tools), but haven't told Python to open the file that way. At least Python 2 gives you a `JSONDecodeError` on line 1 column 1, exactly like you're seeing. (Python 3 may give you a `UnicodeDecodeError` on byte 0 instead; I can't remember…)

Comment: I updated the post with some more information.  There is a google drive link to some of the data if anyone wanted to see it.

Comment: @Kevin I added the data.  I have tried to run it a couple more times and when using the way that you said should be correct, I got an attribute error saying
'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your sample data, I suspect that the problem is that it isn't a valid json document. You effectively have data like:

```
{"a": "b"}
{"c": "d"}
```

`{"a": "b"}` is valid json, and `{"c": "d"}` is valid json, but `{"a": "b"}\n{"c": "d"}` is not valid json. This explains why `json.load(source) fails.

You're on the right track with your second attempt: by reading through the file line-by-line, you can extract the valid json data objects individually. But your implementation has two problems:

- `line` is a string and you can't call `json.load` on a string. That's what `json.loads` is for.
- you can't convert an empty line to a json object.

So if you check for empty lines and use `loads`, you should be able to fill your `tweets` list without any problems.

```
import json
tweets = []
with open("sampledata.txt") as source:
    for line in source:
        if line.strip():
            tweets.append(json.loads(line))

print("Succesfully loaded {} tweets.".format(len(tweets)))
```

Result:

```
Succesfully loaded 2 tweets.
```

Comment: When I try to do this, I still get an error. Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) I tried this with both the sample data I supplied and the full dataset and got the same error each time.  The error specifically comes up at the append portion, so I assume it is still having trouble reading the tweets.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I tried this again on my laptop and it worked.  I don't know why it wasn't working on my other computer, but it works now.  Thank you very much for you help.